# Authentication and Authorization for a simple Web Site

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, openid, saml

I'm struggling with these concepts and having trouble finding good resources on the web.

We are looking for ways to switch out custom implementations tightly integrated into our application for standards based authentication and authorization.

Our scenario is as follows:

- A simple web site (may be an app in the nearby future)
- A user must log in or otherwise gain access (i.e. there's no "guest" content or other things you can do as a guest)
- The site uses its own web services (REST and/or SOAP) on the backend, but it might use 3rd party web services or exposes its own services as 3rd party services for other applications
- Authentication may very well be done by an external provider: Users carry a smartcard and we'd like to have one simple identity provider which reads the smartcard information and sends it back to my simple web site (so I know who the user is and what his role is for instance)
- Other sites might use other methods of authentication (simple username/password for instance), so we might need a configurable Service Provider??

I'm currently looking at OAuth (2) to implement for authorizing use of our REST Services (is it also useful for SOAP?) to our web site, perhaps with a simple "Client Credentials Grant" type.

But for authentication, I'm still none the wiser. There is OpenID, but is it easy enough to build your own OpenID Identity Provider? There is Shibboleth, but it seems to have a steep learning curve for doing custom stuff. And I've looked at just building something from scratch based on the SAML Authentication Request Protocol with an HTTP Post binding. Are there any other options?

Please keep in mind that we want to be flexible with our authentication. For a certain site, we might want to do the smartcard thing, but for another maybe simple username/password login with LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpful still, I personally thought about doing it myself, then discovered a bunch of third parties. I compared (5/18/2015):

- Auth0
- AuthRocket
- UserApp
- DailyCred

**Conclusion for me was Auth0**, because while all the features are very similar, it felt the most legitimate, as in it's not a start-up that might disappear in a few months. Now, the reason that was super important for me was because login is a foundational requirement, so I need to believe as a customer that the Authentication as a Service will be up for as long as I will be.

Here's the full comparison story:
https://medium.com/@bsemaj/authentication-as-a-service-comparison-5-quick-lessons-for-b2b-businesses-e7587275824c

Comment: Ironically, after all 3 days I ditched Auth0 in favor of Devise. I just found the documentation too lacking after all and frustrating to work with. There were so many commands that I thought would be really obviously well documented, e.g., how to sign up, sign in, sign out, change email, change password, but often times I had to go to the source code... My gold standard for docs is Stripe